# How to search for multiple strings in a field in DB2? my query fails with '' (black/empty) values

Tags: db2

Is there a way to build a DB2 query to search a combination of strings in a field?
I am trying to do this:

```
select ITEM, ITEM_DESC
where instr(ITEM_DESC,>parameter1<)>0 
    AND instr(ITEM_DESC,>parameter2<)>0 
    AND instr(ITEM_DESC,>parameter3<)>0 
    AND instr(ITEM_DESC,>parameter4<)>0

UNION

select ITEM, ITEM_DESC
where instr(ITEM_DESC,>parameter5<)>0
    OR instr(ITEM_DESC,>parameter6<)>0 
    OR instr(ITEM_DESC,>parameter7<)>0 
    OR instr(ITEM_DESC,>parameter8<)>0
```

The >parameters< are string inputs for the user, sometimes the user will not use all of them (dynamic list?).
The query works only if all parameters have a string value, when at least one has a '' (empty), the query fails.

Comment: Please, edit your question with complete reproducible example and full error message you get. You may post a link to a similar [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=af008ea552bd528f5190e6d265da8297) as well, which doesn't "fail".

Comment: This sounds like you might want to build your SQL dynamically instead - based on how many parameters where given. If thats not possible, wrap them with COALESCE re-using parameter1 for any other empty parameter COALESCE(>parameter8< , >parameter1<)